# Set DataTextField of DropDownList = ItemIndex

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Can I set property (DataTextField) of DropDownList Control to show the iten index of this item as:

I need to put instead of "xxxxxxxx"  the code that show item index for every Item in DropDownList control 
Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Are you using a DataTable to bind the dropdown?

Comment: No, I use SqlDataSource Control that get data using Stored Procedure in SQl Server Database

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible in the property «DataTextField», but you can utilise the event «OnDataBound» to change te text of each item after the bind is complet.

I hope it's help.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a List of KeyValue pair and bind that to your dropdown control. The value part (of the List of KeyValue pair) can be used to display whatever you want show in the drop down, while the key part (of the List of KeyValue pair) can hold whatever value you would want to use when an item is selected in the drop down.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand how can i do that ?? Please support with code example

Comment: Please check the answer at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499526/c-asp-net-gridview-bind-dropdownlist-to-listkeyvaluepairint-string. He is using a Dictionary object for this. You could follow the same pattern or use a List<KeyValue<type, type>> object, if you chose to.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to set the ListItems Text property to its index using the DataBound event:

**Markup**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropDownList" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqlDataSource1" OnDataBound="dropDownList_DataBound">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**Code**

```
protected void dropDownList_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = 0;
    foreach (ListItem item in dropDownList.Items)
    {
        item.Text = index.ToString();
        index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u very mush <<jdavies>> , its worked very well and it is very easy