# Unable to load data on Select method of Datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

Trying to populate a set of data from datatable to Combobox on the basis of text entered in Combobox. But getting a `System.Data.DataRow` error in the Select method of datatable. 
Following is the code which binds the datatable on Form Load and rebinds data on the call of Search method.

**Note that the search has to be on Tab press not AutoComplete**

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Dim connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()
    Dim table As New DataTable

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       LoadComboBox()
End Sub

 Private Sub LoadComboBox()

        Dim adp As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select stage from sample", connection)
        adp.Fill(table)
        ComboBox1.DataSource = New BindingSource(table, Nothing)
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "stage"

 End Sub

Private Sub Search()
         Dim filteredTable As New DataTable
         Dim filterRow As DataRow()
         Dim str As String = ComboBox1.Text.Trim
         filterRow = table.Select("stage like '%" & ComboBox1.Text.ToString & "%'")
         '**Error in above table(datatable)**       
         For Each rw As DataRow In filterRow
         filteredTable.ImportRow(rw)
         Next

         ComboBox1.DataSource = New BindingSource(filteredTable, Nothing)
         ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "stage"
 End Sub

 Private Sub ComboBox1_PreviewKeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.PreviewKeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
            Search()
        End If
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: See if AutoCompleteMode and AutoCompleteSource would fulfill your requirements.

Comment: @Mary This search has to occur only on Tab press hence I have not used AutoCompleteMode or AutoCompleteSource.

Comment: Where have you declared table?

Comment: @Mary table is declared in the class Form1

Answer (score 0):

in your binding to combo box you have a data table already why are you using a binding source

why not just say ComboBox1.DataSource = filteredTable
Also i would advice you to use Key Value Pair rather than using Like easier binding

Like is regex search at SQL Server this is killing your Database and you are creating overhead over nothing

Key | Value >>
ID  | Name

so taking this from another stack over flow for fast reference
[gridview bind dropdownlist to List<keyvaluePair<int, string>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499526/gridview-bind-dropdownlist-to-listkeyvaluepairint-string)

you can bind a dictionary , datatable , dataview does not matter.

if you want to get text just say your dropdown.text for the ID value dropdown.value if you want to do something later to in the database.

You can make your drop down read only and when user types basically what he is typing is filtering according to what you have binded that way your text search can be made

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dictionary.Add(1, "Home");
dictionary.Add(2, "Work");
dictionary.Add(3, "Mobile");
dictionary.Add(4, "Fax");

dropDown.DataTextField = "Value";
dropDown.DataValueField = "Key";
dropDown.DataSource = dictionary;  //Dictionary<int, string>
dropDown.DataBind();
```

Comment: You're right about the BindingSource, but, as you can see from the objects names used (`Form1`, `EventArgs` etc.), this question is not related to Web development, it's about a WinForms ComboBox. The OP probably doesn't know about the AutoComplete feature or this is an effort to overcome an  Autocomplete limitation (it's triggered only when the text entered matches the starting characters of a string included in the AutocompleteSource list).

Comment: @Jimi Yes this is a WinForm Combobox and the search has to be only on Tab press. Hence I haven't used AutoComplete properties. Could you please suggest an alternative way to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Tried it with a bit of Linq.

```
Private Sub Search()
    Dim filteredTable As New DataTable
    Dim str As String = ComboBox1.Text.Trim
    Dim filterRows = (From row As DataRow In Table.AsEnumerable
                      Where row.Field(Of String)("Name").Contains(ComboBox1.Text)
                      Select row.Field(Of String)("Name")).ToList
    ComboBox1.DataSource = filterRows
End Sub
```

Just substitute your column name for "Name"